# TeamViewer screen resolution Zoom

Tags: screen-resolution, teamviewer

I'm using TeamViewer 13 and the screen resolution is too small to see properly.
Apparently TeamViewer doesn't have any option available.

**Do you have a trick to be able to see properly?** 
Ideally without changing the resolution of the remote screen.

Comment: scroll down for some answers on this post https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-General/Remote-display-too-small-to-see/td-p/5351

Comment: Thanks @tuckbloor I had seen those solutions it's not good for me. I have to work ponctually on the RM I would like to avoid to resize and reboot every single time my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternate solution which avoid you to restart.

In your computer screen setting you can increase the zoom, which will allowed you to scrool on your temviewer window. It's not the best solution but at least you can see better.